How long does is someone required to stay away if removed for trespassing?
I was just watching a breakdown of a police interaction in which a man was arrested for trespassing.  He had been removed from a location the day before and told that if he came back he'd be arrested.  My question is, how long would he have to stay away?  Is he at risk of arrest if he ever comes back even years later, or does the trespass removal expire at some point?
I am interested in answers from any jurisdiction.

Realistically, most people forget about it or do not care after a while.

canada
You ask:

How long does a trespass removal stay in effect?

There is no "duration" of a trespass removal. If police are called to assist in removing someone who is trespassing, that trespass removal is complete when the police release the person. It isn't a thing that expires or has a duration. It just happens.
Trespass is a common-law tort, and also an offence defined by statute in some provinces. Having been removed is not an element of the tort of trespass or the statutory offence.
The tort is completed if you are present, without consent, on someone else's land.
The statutory offence will depend on the province, but for example, in Ontario:

2(1) Every person who is not acting under a right or authority conferred by law and who, without the express permission of the occupier, the proof of which rests on the defendant, enters on premises when entry is prohibited under this Act... is guilty of an offence ...
...
3(1) Entry on premises may be prohibited by notice to that effect ...
...
5(1) A notice under this Act may be given, (a) orally or in writing
...
9(1) A police officer, or the occupier of premises, or a person authorized by the occupier may arrest without warrant any person he or she believes on reasonable and probable grounds to be on the premises in contravention of section 2.

As long as the person is on notice that they are not to enter, they are committing the statutory offence if they enter and would be at risk of being arrested. This is true even had they not been removed by a police officer previously.

You did not answer as far as when it is over.

What ends the time one is on notice, is the question?

Why do you think there would be a fixed time period? If someone wants you off their property, and they don't express otherwise, I would assume they want you off forever.

@Mimedfp nothing on its own ends it.

I suppose a change in the property's ownership would do it.

In Illinois, you can not come back unless the other party is ok with it.
You have to be told to leave though. Typically, the no trespassing warning will be recorded somehow if they really intend to pursue it, so there is no confusion.

Can you cite any actual laws to support this? It seems like this -- and most of your other answers -- are just guesses based on TV or whatever.

@bdb484 well what law do you think relates?

If you don't already know the answer to that, why are you posting an answer?

@bdb484 how is me saying it does not have a time limit wrong and the other right lol

I didn't say you were wrong or that the other answer is right. I said it looks like you're just guessing. Guesses aren't helpful, especially when they aren't based on any meaningful education or experience.

@bdb484 the same would apply for the other answer then is the point.

The other answer discusses actual laws; yours does not.

@bdb484 discussing a law does not answer when the warning to not trespassing ends.

That's an interesting non sequitur. The point is that your answer is useless because it's just a guess, which is why you were invited to clarify whether you actually knew what you were talking about. If not, that's fine; the downvotes accurately reflect the value of your contributions.

If it is not true show that to be the case. @bdb484

I don't even know that you're asking for. What I do know is that there are users with whom it is worthwhile to engage in these types of discussions, and that you have not shown yourself to be one of them. I'll let you have the last word if you'd like it.
